# on adding folder items handle not allowing if statements AppleScript

Tags: while-loop, applescript, repeat

I am having trouble with running anything other than a dialog box within an on adding folder items handle. The code does not go through the if statements. Any help would be appreciated. Code is below:

```
on adding folder items to theAttachedFolder after receiving theNewItems
    set author to theNewItems
    if "blah" is in author then
        set theDialogText to "Blah in filename"
        display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Continue", "Close"} default         button "Close" with icon note
        set author to ""
    else if "lol" is in author then
        set theDialogText to "Lol in file name"
        display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Continue", "Close order"} default button "Close" with icon note
        set author to ""
    else if "ha" is in author then
        set theDialogText to "Ha is in file name"
        display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Continue", "Close"} default button "Close" with icon note
        set author to ""
    else if "omg" is in author then
        set theDialogText to "omg is in file name"
        display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Continue", "close"} default button "Close" with icon note
    end if
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Suggest you read [Folder Actions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH219-SW2) in [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html).  `theNewItems` is a `list` and needs to be treaded as such. BTW Why `author` in `set author to theNewItems`, contextually it makes no sense.

Comment: Also have a look at [Watching Folders](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WatchFolders.html) & [Automator: Folder Actions](http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/folder-action/index.html)

Comment: You deleted your question of Ask Different before I could respond to your comment, does that mean you got it working?

Answer (score 0):

`theNewItems` is a **list** of `alias` specifiers. A comparison of this type with a string fails always.

You have to get the name of the item and you have to iterate the list of files

```
on adding folder items to theAttachedFolder after receiving theNewItems
    repeat with anItem in theNewItems
        tell application "System Events" to set fileName to name of anItem

        if "blah" is in fileName then
            set theDialogText to "Blah in filename"
            display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Continue", "Close"} default button "Close" with icon note
        else if "lol" is in fileName then
            set theDialogText to "Lol in file name"
            display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Continue", "Close order"} default button "Close" with icon note
        else if "ha" is in fileName then
            set theDialogText to "Ha is in file name"
            display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Continue", "Close"} default button "Close" with icon note
        else if "omg" is in fileName then
            set theDialogText to "omg is in file name"
            display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Continue", "close"} default button "Close" with icon note
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```